# Can I connect a Dockerized Spring Boot project to my local MySql Database?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I'm new to Docker and I was wondering if it was posible for me to make a connection between a dockerized spring boot project and a database stored locally in my pc.

I know how to do it in "reverse", creating a MySql server and connecting it to my local Spring project, but I can't find a way to do it in the opposite direction.

Comment: Please check with this `https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-container-to-connect-with-mysql-locally-installed/85000`

Comment: A remark: If possible, I would highly recommend to dockerize the database aswell. It simplifies the setup for other developers.